# Someone help me explain part of this for loop please

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have this code that lets you enter 4 values and it prints the highest value you entered.
I understand everything up until the second for loop, how does it print the highest value? I'm rather new to c# and this is part of a school assignment.
The part of code which is within "**" is what I don't really understand.

```
int[] inputNum = new int[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number: ");
    inputNum[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
**int inputMax = 0;
for(int i2 = 0; i2 < inputNum.Length; i2++)
{

    if(inputNum[i2] > inputMax)
    {
    
        inputMax = inputNum[i2];
    }**
}
Console.WriteLine($"Highest value number: {inputMax}");
```

Comment: I recommend to go through it line by line either on paper or with the debugger, observing when the if condition is entered and the resulting current value of inputMax.

Comment: Buggy code tends to be hard to understand.  Should be `int inputMax = inputNum[0];` and start the loop at 1 to check the rest of the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second loop goes over the numbers that were inputted in the first loop and for each iteration checks if the current number is larger than the previous maximum, and if it is, saves it in `inputMax`. Once the loop is done, you'll be left with the largest number in that variable.

To be honest, though, this problem doesn't really need both loops. If the only requirement is to input four numbers and print out the largest one, there's no need to save them to an array, and you could just perform this check on each number that's inputted.